# Can I use doxygen to document a command-line program?

Tags: python, c, doxygen, command-line-interface

I contribute to a large code project that uses Doxygen to document a series of C libraries. We are also starting to use doxygen with [doxypy](http://code.foosel.org/doxypy) for associated python modules.

Is there an easy way to document command-line programs (in python or C), and their command line options, (automatically) using doxygen?

Comment: Do you want to create a man-like page starting from the doxygen comments ? Am I right ?

Comment: Yes. Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to generate `man` pages, you need to set `GENERATE_MAN` tag to Yes (.doxyfile).

By default, a sub-folder named man is created within the directory provided using `OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` to contain the pages generated.

By doing that, doxygen will render all the markup you added to the source code as a man page (one page for each translation unit).

At this point, you might want to exclude certain parts you want to ignore (I assume you are interested in showing only how to call the main) using the [exclude* directives](http://www.doxygen.nl/config.html#exclude).

I advise you to compile two different doxyfiles: one for internal usage (complete javadoc-like documentation), the other for producing the program man and the like.

Of course, you will not get the expected result at the first try and you might need to play with doxygen markup a bit.

Comment: Sounds exactly what I need (untested). Thanks.